# Angular ng tags-input key-property should be id/name on a dropdown selection not working

Tags: javascript, angularjs, ng-tags-input

Suppose there are two dropdowns, one is a normal dropdown and the other is tags-input.  Now I want to set the key property of tags-input based on the normal dropdown.  When a user selects normal dropdown with an option1, I want to set the tags-input 'key-property' as 'id' and when he selects option2, I want to set the tags-input 'key-property' as 'name'.  But, am facing issue, before the key-property get set to new one(eg: name), the old value is getting tracked(eg: id) and throws dupes error.

eg:

```
<tags-input  
type="text” 
data-ng-model="value”  
display-property="display_name"
key-property="{{getKeyProperty(selectedDropdownId)}}">
<auto-complete
   source="filterAutoCompletion.fetchFilterAutoSugtn($event,addFilts.key,$query,false,filterIndex)”>
</auto-complete>
</tags-input>
```

And since it track's by id when it should track by name and vice versa it throws dupes error.